# Can we stop synchronous request made? How?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could help me how to stop a synchronous request made to the server, especially while moving from background to foreground.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a normal NSURLConnection you could just send it the cancel command. ([docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

init like:

```
 NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

cancel like so:

```
[connection cancel];
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply however i don't have access to get the connection variable as well as its being done in a library file. Please suggest me the best solution for the above comment made...

Comment: Quick 'n dirty: edit the lib to have to expose the connection. Eg. like so: - (NSURLConnection *) connection { return _connection; } Alternativly you might want to handle the connection yourself, its easy enough why use a lib at all?

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about `+[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]`? In that case you can not stop this request.

If you need to potentially stop a network operation in mid flight, then you need to use an asynchronous API. I personally prefer to roll my own using `NSURLConnection` and what is the least amount of work for the current task, usually a `NSOperation` or just some GCD. I strongly suggest that you learn how to use `NSURLConnection` even if you choose to use some other approach.

One such other approach is [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), that wraps `NSURLConnection` is a `NSOperation` that you can call `cancel` on.

Comment: Hey thanks for that, I have got some library files which uses synchronous connection and cannot modify the code now. Im making a call to server in another thread and when navigating from background to foreground, I am checking if that thread is still executing and if so i am canceling it to avoid a crash, however I am still getting crash in low network connectivity which says "iphone failed to resume in time". I would like to fix this issue, can you please help me out?

Comment: @Nitu Not short of actually implementing cancelation. When your app is requested to resume, then you have 20 seconds to respond or else the watchdog kills you. Changing the code not not use synchronous network access is your only solution.

Comment: @Nitu I do not know how to be more clear. You can not cancel synchronous network access. You must be able to cancel network access on app resume or else the watchdog kills the app. Add the two and there is just one conclusion to be made; you must abandon synchronous network access and use some asynchronous method.